# Send user email 24 hours after inactivity, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

Basically, I want to send an email reminder to a User if they haven't made any posts within 24 hours of being created. I am confused on how to send an email without first making an action, such as `create` or `update`.

**controller** *users_controller.rb*

```
def run
  @user = current_user
  if Time.now.utc == @user.created_at + 24.hours && @user.microposts.empty?
    UserMailer.twentyfour_email(@user).deliver
  end
end
```

**mailer** *user_mailer.rb*

```
def twentyfour_mailer
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Post something on the site!')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this to happen via a controller action, you just need a cron job to fire off a task (the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem does this).  That might look like:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "User.notify_lazy_users"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy.

You can use [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for instance.

```
UserMailer.twentyfour_mailer.delay(run_at: 24.hours.from_now)
```